# Not receiving updated data from the database

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, nestjs, typeorm, nestjs-typeorm

My Nestjs app & another codeigniter php app are connected to a common database.  In NestJS whenever I query some row which was previously updated by the Codeigniter app, I'm not getting the latest value. I'll get the latest value once I restart the NestJS app. I think some db level lock is causing this issue. Any help is appreciated.

My Typeorm config

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  inject: [ConfigService],
  imports: [ConfigModule],
  useFactory: async (
    configService: ConfigService,
  ) => {
    const dbConfig = configService.get<MysqlConfig>('mysql');
    return {
      autoLoadEntities: true,
      type: 'mysql',
      host: dbConfig.dbHost,
      username: dbConfig.dbUsername,
      password: dbConfig.dbPassword,
      database: dbConfig.dbName,
      port: dbConfig.dbPort,
      synchronize: true,
      subscribers: [],
      dropSchema: false,
      cache: false, 
      logging: dbConfig.logging,
      migrations: [join(__dirname, 'migrations', '*{.ts,.js}')],
    };
  }
})
```